# How to use GROUP BY with SELF JOIN?

Tags: sql-server, group-by, self-join

I have a person table which holds person and his manager at the same time.
I'm using SELF JOIN to select managers email but I get a lot of duplicates.
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/3/withoutgroupby.png
How can I use GROUP BY with my query

```
SELECT              P.prs_id AS 'Employee_id', M.prs_id AS 'Manager_id', M.prs_email AS 'Manager_email'
FROM                qrd_prs_person AS P
LEFT OUTER JOIN     qrd_prs_person AS M  
ON                  P.prs_manager_number = M.prs_number
```

> GROUP BY   M.prs_id

If I add this line at the end of my query to group by Manager_id, I receive this error

> Column 'qrd_prs_person.prs_id' is invalid in the select list because
>   it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY
>   clause.

Comment: Not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: What is the desired output of your query?  GROUP BY will only work if you had something like `COUNT(M.prs_id)`

Comment: Without a Group by I receive a lot of dublicate values, i dont know if Group By is my solution cause it gives an error

Comment: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/3/withoutgroupby.png/

Comment: But, once again, what exactly are you trying to achieve? Do you want a list of all managers? Or a list of all employees with their manager information? Or..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you're trying to achieve?

If you're after a query that returns one row per employee, with two optional columns containing the manager's info, then your original query is correct (without the group by).  The relationship is many-to-one, you're starting with a row per "many" that each has a single (optional) "one", so there is no need to group by.

This however is assuming that your data is correct and that prs_number is in fact unique for each employee.  If you have two or more managers sharing a prs_number, you will end up with people having multiple managers.

By making this an outer join you're also returning people without a manager (i.e. top of the food chain :)), was this your intention?

**EDIT**

If you want only managers returned, then you can't keep the first column (P.prs_id) and get one row per manager.  If you want the list of people that manage one or more people, this will do the trick:

```
SELECT              M.prs_id AS 'Manager_id', M.prs_email AS 'Manager_email'
FROM                qrd_prs_person AS P
INNER JOIN          qrd_prs_person AS M  
ON                  P.prs_manager_number = M.prs_number
GROUP BY            M.prs_id, M.prs_email
```

Comment: This one gets rid of the dublicate ones indeed, with the cost of the first column. First column was (prs_id) unique and different persons can have the same manager so I kept getting dublicate emails

Comment: You could also use DISTINCT to get rid of duplicates.

Comment: The first column was **P**.prs_id, as in P for Person, as in not a manager.  To include the prs_id's of all direct reports would require a row for each, thus taking you back to your original problem of having duplicate manager emails.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you want to group by, since I see no Min, Max, Sum or anything that requires grouping ?
Maybe an `order by` would suffice ? Anyway, if you `GROUP BY`, any column that's not SUMmed or MINed etc **MUST** be present in the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 0):

All your columns in select statement need to be either grouped by or they need to have an aggregate function, you can try adding MAX(qrd_prs_person.prs_id) and see if it works. Should help you :-)

Also you will need to add the email id part in group by part, else use MAX()
Your query should be

```
SELECT  MAX(P.prs_id) AS 'Employee_id', 
        M.prs_id AS 'Manager_id', 
        M.prs_email AS 'Manager_email'
FROM                
    qrd_prs_person AS P
    LEFT OUTER JOIN     
        qrd_prs_person AS M  ONP.prs_manager_number = M.prs_number
GROUP BY 
    M.prs_id, M.prs_email
```

Comment: Yeah well, this query will run and return some result. But what sense does it make to select the MAX P.prs_id from the group? I really think that questions like this one should not be answered directly. Better ask the person: what is his real intention?

Comment: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/204/withoutgroupby.png/       I wanted to receive DISTINCT email adresses from my person table. However prs_id is unique and different persons can have the same manager so I keep getting dublicate emails

Answer (score 0):

If you were using MySQL, it would just take one of the M.prs_id values from the group. But these values may be different inside the group, so it doesn't really make sense to just pick a random one of them. That's why SQL Server complains.

I think you just misunderstood how GROUP BY works. What exactly are you trying to achieve with this query?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you do a `group by`, suddenly you have many possible answers for the contents of `P.prs_id AS 'Employee_id'` in your select clause. (One for each of the employees of a manager.) SQL Sever wants to know exactly what you want to go there, so it's insisting that you provide some way of totaling  up all the values of that into one value.

Probably you want to get a count of employees, so just replace it with `COUNT(P.prs_id) AS 'Employee_count'`.

You will also need to add `M.prs_email` to your group by clause.

Comment: I want to see only DISTINCT email adresses per Manager id(M.prs_id)